# How to create a condition for the future input variables in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

I have a dataframe like the below:

```
df1:
Pan_no.     Last_broker_cat
Xxx             Mutual fund
Yyy            National distributor
ZZZ            National Distributor
Aaa              Debt champion
BBB            National distributor
Ccc              Debt champion
```

I am mapping each value of Last_broker_cat column to an unique number :

```
df1['Last_broker_cat] = df1['Last_broker_cat].map({'National distributor':1,'Mutual fund':2, 'debt_champion :3})
```

Now my df1 looks like the below:

```
df1

Pan_no.     Last_broker_cat
Xxx            2
Yyy            1
ZZZ            1
Aaa            3
BBB            1
Ccc            3
```

Now I have a condition:

In the future input variable, if there are any new value in the Last_broker_cat column apart from the existing one I need to assign it with the unique number that I have assigned to the least occuring value in the dataframe.
Eg in our dataframe the least occuring value is 2 so any new value that comes in the future should be assigned with the least value.
How can I code this condition in python?

Comment: Which value should be picked when several values are the least occurring, e.g. ``Last_broker_cat`` is ``2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 3, 2``?

Comment: That will not be the case in my file. Since I have more than 10million records. There will only be one value that is least occuring

Comment: So you only ever need to append no more than one value? In your example, appending a second line would lead to the situation described above. Or does the least occurring value depend only on the *initial* values?

Comment: No no sorry  the input will be refreshed every month so the least might change due to the new records

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
df['Last_broker_cat'] = pd.factorize(df['Last_broker_cat'])[0]
```

But the unique values start from 0 to n unique values.